# fastCGI in nginx and centOS

Tags: php, centos, nginx, fastcgi

I was following [this](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2009/install-nginx-php-5-3-and-fastcgi-on-centos-fedora-red-hat-rhel/) tutorial, I got it to a point where I was to test if I can run the /etc/init.d/phpfgci start command. However it gives me this error:

```
Starting service:spawn-fcgi: can't find user name nginx
[root@Server /]#                                           [FAILED]
```

I installed nginx directly from the source code, not using yum (tutorial uses yum)... can this be the problem? Reason why I am not using yum to install is because it doesn't give me the updated version of nginx. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create nginx user:

```
# /usr/sbin/useradd nginx -s /bin/false
```